# K.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. use GradientTape instead. How do i replace it directly in my code

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Below mentioned are my lines of code. Line 1 initializes the custom VGG16 model (all max pool layers are replaced by average pool. Line too initializes the target. Line three formulates the loss function and line four is the line that throws the error

```
content_model = VGG16_AvgPool_CutOff(shape, 11)
target = K.variable(content_model.predict(x))
loss = K.mean(K.square(target - content_model.output))
grads = K.gradients(loss, content_model.input)
```

ERROR:

```
tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As shown in error, Please use `GradientTape` in place of `gradients` because `gradients` is not supported in tensorflow eager mode, if you are using `Tensorflow > 2.0`

```
grads = tf.GradientTape(loss, content_model.input)
```